# Pop-Up form not appearing in bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I wrote a code for pop up form for submitting data when clicked on Edit link in a bootstrap website:
Code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#modal-body").modal('show');
    });
</script>  
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                      <h3>Send me a message</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form class="contact" name="contact">
                        <label class="label" for="name">Your Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                        <label class="label" for="email">Your E-mail</label><br>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge"><br>
                        <label class="label" for="message">Enter a Message</label><br>
                        <textarea name="message" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
                      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nah.</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div id="thanks"><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content">Edit!</a></p></div>
```

But pop up form isn't appearing. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1) Remove the "hide" class from your modal html:

```
<div id="form-content" class="modal fade in" style="display: none;">
```

2) Target the actual modal with your jQuery instead of the modal-body:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form-content").modal('show');
});
```

This seems to work for me, as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4rpgoth3/).  Let me know if this is not the effect you are looking for.  Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I need to apply css to make form more presentable.

Answer (score 1):

`modal-body` is a class, but you're treating it like an id in the script.

You should change the class to an id, or amend the script.

Comment: Can you give me the working code? I changed `modal-body` to id, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `$("#modal-body").modal('show');` to `$(".modal-body").modal('show');`